# Static ConcurrentDictionary to maintain static objects

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am using following code to maintain some static information. The problem I see with it is that, if the information retrieved using GeKeysFromCache is modified without using lock keyword it may lead to exceptions in a multithreaded environment. Is there a way to improve this implementation?

```
public class CacheHelper
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<InstanceField>> m_InstancesCached = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<InstanceField>>();
    private static readonly Object _entriesLock = new object();

    public List<InstanceField> GeKeysFromCache(string cacheKey)
    {
        return m_InstancesCached.GetOrAdd(cacheKey, (key) =>
        {
            return new List<InstanceField>();
        });
    }

    public void AddKeysToCache(string cacheKey, List<InstanceField> inputs)
    {
        m_InstancesCached.AddOrUpdate(cacheKey, inputs, (key, oldValue) =>
        {
            lock (_entriesLock)
            {
                oldValue.AddRange(inputs);
                return oldValue;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Test Code: Without lock keyword it fails

```
public class ThreadSafeCachingTest
{
    private static readonly Object _entriesLock = new object();
    public ThreadSafeCachingTest()
    {
    }

    public void Invoke()
    {
        var thread1Completed = false;
        var thread2Completed = false;
        var thread3Completed = false;
        var threadList = new List<Thread>();

        var instanceName = "MyInstance";
        var beforeCachingData = (new CacheHelper()).GeKeysFromCache(instanceName);

        threadList.Add(new Thread(() =>
        {
            //lock (_entriesLock)
            //{
            var instanceFields1 = (new CacheHelper()).GeKeysFromCache(instanceName);
            instanceFields1 = instanceFields1 ?? new List<InstanceField>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                instanceFields1.Add(new InstanceField() { FieldName = "FieldName-" + i.ToString() });
            }
            thread1Completed = true;
            //}
        }));


        threadList.Add(new Thread(() =>
        {
            //lock (_entriesLock)
            //{
            var instanceFields2 = (new CacheHelper()).GeKeysFromCache(instanceName);
            instanceFields2 = instanceFields2 ?? new List<InstanceField>();

            for (int i = 10000; i < 20000; i++)
            {
                instanceFields2.Add(new InstanceField() { FieldName = "FieldName-" + i.ToString() });
            }
            thread2Completed = true;
            //}
        }));

        threadList.Add(new Thread(() =>
        {
            //lock (_entriesLock)
            //{
            while (!(thread1Completed && thread2Completed && thread3Completed))
            {
                var instanceFields3 = (new CacheHelper()).GeKeysFromCache(instanceName);
                if (instanceFields3.Count > 0)
                {
                    instanceFields3.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    thread3Completed = true;
                }
                //}
            }
        }));

        foreach (Thread t in threadList) t.Start();
        foreach (Thread t in threadList) t.Join();

        var afterCachingData = (new CacheHelper()).GeKeysFromCache(instanceName);
    }
}

public class InstanceField
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've never used a ConcurrentDictionary, but presumably all its methods are thread safe. So are you actually asking about making modifications to a `List<InstanceField>` in a thread-safe way?

Comment: @eurotrash Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was missing was something very trivial, adding a ToList() to  GeKeysFromCache makes it ThreadSafe

```
public class CacheHelper
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<InstanceField>> m_InstancesCached = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<InstanceField>>();
    private static readonly Object _entriesLock = new object();

    public List<InstanceField> GeKeysFromCache(string cacheKey)
    {
        var resultSet = m_InstancesCached.GetOrAdd(cacheKey, (key) =>
       {
           return new List<InstanceField>();
       });

        lock (_entriesLock)
        {
            return resultSet.ToList();
        }
    }

    public void AddKeysToCache(string cacheKey, List<InstanceField> inputs)
    {
        m_InstancesCached.AddOrUpdate(cacheKey, inputs, (key, oldValue) =>
        {
            lock (_entriesLock)
            {
                oldValue.AddRange(inputs);
                return oldValue;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public List<InstanceField> GeKeysFromCache(string cacheKey)
> {
>     var resultSet = m_InstancesCached.GetOrAdd(cacheKey, (key) =>
>    {
>        return new List<InstanceField>();
>    });
>
>     return resultSet.ToList();
> }
> ```

Why so many `return`s and when you can simply do this with only one `return` and without the lambda:

```
return m_InstancesCached.GetOrAdd(cacheKey, new List<string>()).ToList();
```